Windows kbhit() has weird wide char issues
I'm writing a simple chat program and i'm using conio's _kbhit() with _getwch() to get input from user.
The problem is when I enter altgr combinations (like altgr-s for letter 'ś' in Polish programmers keyboard) the terminal window becomes invisible, but the process is still running (responds to sockets and is visible in task manager).
I'm setting the locale to ".UTF8"
Due to my testing I'm sure it's the problem with _kbhit() and not _getwch().
I don't want to switch to PDCurses because I use the windows api and i don't think mixing is a good idea.
I'd maybe go with PeekConsoleInputW() and ReadConsoleInput() but when I tried them the program has noticeable input lag and there was still problems with polish letters
Anyone had that problem before, how did you sort it out? Is there a kbhit() alternative?

sounds a little bit like a keyboard shortcut of the OS or the terminal window. What happens to the terminal window when you type altgr+s without running your program?

This is specific to whatever compiler you are using. Most folks stopped use console I/O other than command line arguments when MS DOS was abandoned.

"Wide character" doesn't mean at all the same thing as "Unicode", and especially not the same thing as "UTF-8".  You're dealing with details of the Windows terminal interfaces here, which I can't respond to directly, but I rate it fairly likely that if the terminal is operating in UTF-8 mode then you can expect to read variable-length UTF-8 code sequences from it, for which the regular character I/O functions would be appropriate.
